# Why texts/bevelled curves not showing up just untill converting to mesh in Eevee?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, text-object

Why are texts/bevelled curves not showing up until converted to mesh in Eevee? I have this happen only on my new PC.

Also to be able to work in Eevee I have to enable High Quality Normals, which is weird for me, and I feel that it may not be the proper way.

[image: High Quality ON]

[image: Converted to mesh][image: No Hight Quality on]

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question and add images that show your issue. Thanks

Comment: An external link is not what is expected here. Please add images directly in your question. Thanks

Comment: Is it a AMD gpu?

Comment: yes, and the cpu as well